# Error: free(): invalid pointer displayed when executing ogr2ogr on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ogr2ogr, bash

Hello I'm getting an error when executing ogr2ogr tool when running bash file:

> free(): invalid pointer save_maps_to_db.sh: line 5: 301101 Aborted
> (core dumped) ogr2ogr -f "$format" PG:"$connection_string"
> $source_name -nln boundary_maps -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -append Processed
> source/my_map.norm.geo.json

The bash code executing would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
format="PostgreSQL"
connection_string="dbname=db host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=pass"
for filename in source_2/*.norm.geo.json; do
  echo "Starting " $filename
  source_name=$filename
  ogr2ogr -f "$format" PG:"$connection_string" $source_name -nln boundary_maps -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -append
  echo "Processed " $filename
done
```

For each file it displays the error, but it seems to do its job normally; the funny part is that the same code runs without error messages on windows; perhaps I'm missing something...